# Change a range of cells on one or more sheets based on a selected range of cells in a main sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to preface this by saying that I'm largely inexperienced with coding. I've been working on a project at work on my own, and finally ran into a wall that I can't solve by simple googling.

To explain briefly with pertinent details, I have a workbook with a varying number of worksheets that each have a specific cell for text (explained later), and a checkbox.

My goal is to select a range of cells, usually 1-5 in a row, and then have a button to change the color of the same selected cells of all sheets given a specific criteria. The criteria being that only the sheets that have "Office" listed in the aforementioned cell, and the check box un-checked, will be changed.

While I have no issue having Excel cycle through the sheets and do something only on the sheets that meet the criteria, the problem comes with trying to edit the same cells as are selected on the main sheet.

The coding I have come up with so far:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim n As Integer
Set cell = Selection
If Range("AN6").Text = "Office" Then
    For n = 1 To Sheets.Count - 2
        If Sheets(n).Range("AN6").Text = "Office" And Sheets(n).CheckBox1.value = False Then
            For Each cell In Selection
                Sheets(n).Range(cell).Interior.ColorIndex = 56
            Next cell
        End If
    Next n
End If
```

The error I am getting is: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Hopefully there is a way to execute this. I'd greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .Address property of a range. I'm pretty sure you're getting an error because your selection is in one sheet, and you try to refer to that range in another sheet. Using just the address of the range should fix that issue.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim n As Integer
Set cell = Selection
If Range("AN6").Text = "Office" Then
    For n = 1 To Sheets.Count - 2
        If Sheets(n).Range("AN6").Text = "Office" And Sheets(n).CheckBox1.value = False Then
            For Each cell In Selection
                Sheets(n).Range(cell.Address(False,False)).Interior.ColorIndex = 56
            Next cell
        End If
    Next n
End If
```

The only testing I did on this code was using this sub. I selected a range on my worksheet and ran the macro and the msg box said Q12:U26

```
Sub test()
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Selection
    MsgBox cell.Address(False, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for the first sheet that met the criteria, but when it got to the second one it came up with the same error.

Comment: Scratch that, I had the other sheets protected so I had to unprotect them as needed to solve the issue. Thanks! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub test()

    With Selection
        startRow = .Cells(1).Row
        startColumn = .Cells(1).Column
        endRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        endColumn = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
    End With
    If Range("AN6").Text = "Office" Then
        For n = 1 To Sheets.Count - 2
            If Sheets(n).Range("AN6").Text = "Office" And Sheets(n).CheckBox1.value = False Then
                For Each cell In Range(Sheets(n).Cells(startRow, startColumn), Sheets(n).Cells(endRow, endColumn))
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 56
                Next cell
            End If
        Next n
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error on the "For Each cell" line.